# Add method to javascript's Window object before the page starts loading

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to add a method to a dynamically created iframe's Window object before the requested page starts loading? I would expect to do this though `iframe.contentWindow.myMethod = function() { }`, however iframe.contentWindow is NULL before the page loads.

I can add the method when the onload event fires, however some pages make an inline call to the method I'm adding. As the browser executes code when received 'method doesn't exist' errors are being raised.

I'm hoping there is a point I can get access to the window object as soon as it is created, before the content is downloaded and processed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm hoping there is a point I can get access to the window object as soon as it is created, before the content is downloaded and processed?

I very much doubt there is. Perhaps you could modify the pages being loaded so that they call the method in the parent window instead, where you know you'll already have the method defined. E.g., instead of them doing:

```
someMethod("some arg");
```

they'd do

```
parent.someMethod("some arg");
```

...where `someMethod` is a global function within the opening window.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/anahic/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/anahic/1/edit) | [Source of iframe](http://jsbin.com/egucij/1/edit)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm currently doing, I was hoping to get rid of the call to parent purely to keep the usage cleaner. Looks like I'm out of luck :(

Comment: @WDuffy: Well, if you control the pages being loaded, they can define the function themselves. Or, of course, you could put `var someMethod = parent.someMethod;` at the top of them, and then they just use `someMethod("some arg");` to make the call. JavaScript is nothing if not flexible about these things. :-)

Answer (score -2):

You can't modify a page before it *starts* loading - there's nothing there to modify. You can modify it *while* it's loading - using a `<script>` tag at the top of `<head>` that executes directly, rather than waiting until `onload`. That's about the soonest you can do it, though.